# How to parse NSMutableDictionary in Swift programming?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

In my apple watch interface controller "reply" object contains Json response in NSDictionary. Here is my response i need the  "accountName" from this below response. How to parse it in Swift programming.

```
[Accounts: (
    {
    accountName = "ABCD";
    idNumber = 114000093;
    email = "xyz@gmail.com";
    index = 0;
    nickName = "Suites";
    },
    {
    accountName = "EFGH";
    idNumber = 114000094;
    email = "abc@gmail.com";
    index = 1;
    nickName = "Sultan";
   }
)]
```

I have tried like below:

```
WKInterfaceController.openParentApplication(["request" : "GetData"], reply: { (reply, error) -> Void in

        println(reply)

        self.accountNames = reply["Accounts"] as? NSMutableArray
         println(self.accountNames)
```

Comment: Plz post some code, whatever you have tried, so we can idea about variable and solve if there is problem

Comment: @ViralSavaj i have updated my code please look into it once.

Comment: Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy, you can try out by your own, and can google also, there are lots and lots of example available, you just need to brush up little bit.

Btw, You can try like this,

```
let accountArray : NSArray = reply.objectForKey("Accounts") as! NSArray
let accountDic : NSDictionary = accountArray.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
let accountName : NSString = accountDic.valueForKey("accountName") as! NSString
```

Hope, this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
let accountInfos = (reply.valueForKey("Accounts") as [NSDictionary]).map {
                YourModelClass(accountName: $0["accountName"] as String, idNumber: $0["idNumber"] as String ..... same for all other)
            }
            self.yourMutableArray.addObjectsFromArray(accountInfos)
let accountName = (yourMutableArray.objectAtIndex(0)as YourModelClass).accountName
println(accountName)
```

And your model class :

```
   class YourModelClass : NSObject {
       var accountName : String?
       .
       .
       init(accountName:String, ......) {
            self.accountName = accountName
}
```